# Moving a div from inside one div to another div using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In prototype or normal-but-cross-browser-compatible Javascript, how do I move the contents of a div to the contents of another div?

Inside the div is a form with ids and dependent Javascript code with event observers. I don't want this to break just because I have moved a block in the DOM. A 'this innerHTML = that innerHTML' solution is not what I am looking for. I will also be needing to do this when the DOM is loaded.

I want to go from this:

```
<div id='here'>
    <div id='MacGuffin'>
    <p>Hello Worlds!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='there'>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id='here'>
</div>
<div id='there'>
    <div id='MacGuffin'>
    <p>Hello Worlds!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...when the document loads with nothing jumping about.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can add this at the very end of the BODY tag:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('there').appendChild(
    document.getElementById('MacGuffin')
  );
</script>
```

`MacGuffin` will be moved automatically from one to the other.
And there won't be any flickering.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Worked nicely although I did not go for the BODY tag, I went for the prototype on DOM load method.

Comment: Glad it worked. I don't know well prototype, but if I remember well `$('there').appendChild( $('MacGuffin') )` could work too.

Comment: You may choose to write the code inside an window.onload = function(){document.getElement...}, than you can place it right beside the 'there' object. Not at the end of BODY. With this trick I was able to place a banner loaded in the dynamic top of the page to the static bottom of my page.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not a major point, but there is no Node.migrateChild() built-in Javascript interface method.  If a fragment already has a parent elsewhere in the DOM (as div id='MacGuffin' does in example markup above), appendChild() quietly detaches the argument fragment from any current parent before reattaching under the new parent.  In my mind migrateChild() would be a more semantically meaningful method name than appendChild(), less need for StackOverflow developer searches to allude to its more powerful abilities.

Answer (score 2):

To move the *contents* of `here` into `there`, this works, as long as `here` encloses everything you want to move, like a `<div>`:

```
$('there').insert($('here').descendants()[0]);
```

descendants() returns an array, and insert takes content, so use the first element.

Answer (score -1):

To move the *contents* of `here` into `there`, you're basically after:

```
$('there').insert($('here').childNodes);
```

Sadly, that doesn't work.

As with the other two answers, it looks like you have to resort to plain JavaScript with prototype only providing a shorthand for `document.getElementById`.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var c = $('nav').firstChild, n; c; c = n) {
    n = c.nextSibling;
    frag.appendChild(c);
}
$('header').appendChild(frag);
```

(See John Resign's blog for performance stats on DocumentFragments:
http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that for me. I wasn't able to use the shorthand $ but @Mic's suggestion worked fine. I was able to use Prototype for running the move on DOM load but I was surprised there was no Prototype solution.

Comment: This works but seems overly complicated. I believe the answer by @Jim works better.