# Move div content into another div using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML setup:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="text">One</div>
    <div class="text">One</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
    <div class="text">Two</div>
    <div class="text">Two</div>
</div>
```

I want to move the content of div `.two` into `.one` using pure javascript (not jQuery) so we get:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="text">One</div>
    <div class="text">One</div>
    <div class="text">Two</div>
    <div class="text">Two</div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this with *millisecond* performance in mind?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329108/moving-a-div-from-inside-one-div-to-another-div-using-prototype

Comment: I came across that Q&A too, but I think this question stands on its own (with the micro-performance in consideration).

Comment: Give div id 1,2 and use javascript :  document.getElementById('1').appendChild(
    document.getElementById('2')
  );  tried it??

Comment: Will these elements have event handlers attached to them before they are moved?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes they will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally prefer [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) as it gives you more control as to where to put elements, *but be careful to take note of its browser support*.

```js
const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const two = document.querySelector('.two');

[...two.children].forEach(element => {
  one.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', element);
});
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="text">One</div>
    <div class="text">One</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
    <div class="text">Two</div>
    <div class="text">Two</div>
</div>
```

Also note that I've used ES2015 syntax.

Comment: Any chance of doing a performance comparison to James' answer since both vary in approach?

Comment: Also, browser support for `insertAdjacentElement()` seems to be fine: https://caniuse.com/#feat=insert-adjacent

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I would if I have time, but feel free to test it yourself on jsperf.com

Comment: @HenrikPetterson thankfully this solution also retains event listeners http://jsbin.com/zuwonabuli/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 4):

The possible duplicate question actually has a native answer - use [.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to move the nodes.

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
var one = document.querySelector(".one");
var children = document.querySelector(".two").children;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function (child) {
    one.appendChild(child);
});
```

You can loop over it with a `while` loop and use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) if you're after the performance boost.

```
var one = document.querySelector(".one");
var children = document.querySelector(".two").children;
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

while (children.length) {
    frag.appendChild(children[0]);
}

one.appendChild(frag);
```

Faster solution ([source](https://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-insertadjacentelement/1)):

```
var one = document.querySelector(".one");
var children = [...document.querySelector(".two").children];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var i = 0;
var il = children.length;

while (i < il) {
    frag.appendChild(children[i]);
    i += 1;
}

one.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work properly, please see https://jsfiddle.net/phsxm0y5/

Comment: Yup - forgot about `.children` being a live list - fixed the code and the example https://jsfiddle.net/phsxm0y5/1/

Comment: Lovely! Any chance of doing a performance comparison to evolutionxbox's answer since both vary in approach?

Comment: I put together a JSPerf test https://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-insertadjacentelement - evolutionbox's version seems to be faster than mine - wouldn't have guessed that

Comment: @JamesLong I wanted to comment about redraws, and your's probably being the faster solution. But after thinking about it, I guess evolutionbox's version only fires redraws for each element, while yours fires for each move to the fragment, and then at least one extra for appending the fragment.

Comment: @Yoshi - evolutionbox's also doesn't rely on a live list, which slows my one down. If that's factored out, mine is the faster solution ... sometimes

Comment: These elements *do* have event handlers attached to them. Will this solution still work? Thank you for the tests.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson yes - appendChild will retain event listeners (I imagine insertAdjacentElement will as well, but I've not tested it). innerHTML will not unless you delegate your events

Comment: @HenrikPetterson - there's not much in it, but evolutionbox's seems to be faster every now and again. If the speed is important, test both solutions with real data rather than this demo, but the numbers seem to be hinting that evolutionbox's solution will win

Comment: @JamesLong I wouldn't have guessed that either.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript, compatible with most browser and old versions, use **querySelector** as its better in performance to get the first found class instead **getElementsByClassName** thats returns an array.

```
var one = document.querySelector('.one');
var two = document.querySelector('.two');
```

If you want to set it as last children, then:

```
while(two.children.length>0)
    one.appendChild(two.children[0]);
```

If you want it as first children, then move the content ***before the first child*** of ***one***:

```
while(two.children.length>0)
    one.insertBefore(two.children[0], one.firstChild);
```

And last, useful for similar cases a clean replacement for ***one*** could be with:

```
one.innerHTML = two.innerHTML;
```

Note: this last implementation removes all content of **"one"** and sets the content by **"two"**